# Playwright Component Testing

Tags: playwright

does anybody write component tests in small with Playwright?
https://www.guru99.com/component-testing.html
Any idea how to do it in Angular2 app?
Any kind of example is helpful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.22, Playwright has started supporting component testing. Here is the link for official [documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-components)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to checkout my library for writing component tests with Angular and Playwright: https://github.com/sand4rt/playwright-ct-angular. See example below:

```js
// button.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  selector: 'button-component',
  template: `<button>{{title}}</button>`,
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() title!: string;
}
```

```js
// button.component.test.ts
import { test, expect } from '@sand4rt/experimental-ct-angular';
import { ButtonComponent } from './components/button.component';

test('render props', async ({ mount }) => {
  const component = await mount(ButtonComponent, {
    props: {
      title: 'Submit',
    },
  });
  await expect(component).toContainText('Submit');
});
```